# Zero Padding Bash/Shell

Tags: bash, shell

I need to the last 3 chars say 002 and decrement it by 1 001. I currently have a problem whereby it is converting it to an int. So 001 becomes 1. What I am trying to do is use the printf and convert it back to 001. However this seems to not work for me. I have the following:

```
set -x

substring()
{
    VAR=$1
    OFFSET=$2
    LENGTH=$3
    RET_VAL=${VAR:$OFFSET:$LENGTH}
}

# $1 filename

# Change to PF Gazetteer directory
cd $CARRIER_PF_UPDATES_DIR

LOG=log.txt
DownloadedFile=$1
OldFile=
DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S")
RET=0

if [ "${2+1}" == "1" ]
then
    echo "Date: " $DATE > $LOG
    echo "filename: " $DownloadedFile >> $LOG
fi

substring ${DownloadedFile} -3 3
extension=$RET_VAL
old_ext=$((${extension}+1))

substring ${DownloadedFile} 0 9
echo $RET_VAL
oldFile="${RET_VAL}${old_ext}"
oldFile= `printf "%020d" ${RET_VAL}`
oldFile="${oldFile}.${old_ext}"

#printf '%03d\n' 1

echo $oldFile

# move any temporary files if they exist
mv "${DownloadedFile}~" ${DownloadedFile}

# check to see if we got a file
result=$(grep 226 run.ilog)


if [ "${2+1}" == "1" ]
then
    echo "grep found: " $result >> $LOG
fi

if [ -e "${DownloadedFile}" ]
then
   #add back onto filename
   #store back onto var = $OldFile
   #Check if OldFile exist
   #Cat files together and - Cat oldFile DownloadedFile > tempFile
echo ""
fi

if [ "$result" == "" ]
then
     # File not found
     RET=100
else
     RET=10
     # START F4202
     sorted=$(sort -t'+' -k7 ${fileName} > ${fileName}.sorted)
     if [ -e "${fileName}.sorted" ]
     then
        mv "${fileName}" "unsorted/${fileName}.unsorted"
        mv "${fileName}.sorted" ${fileName}
     fi
     # END F4202
fi

if [ "${2+1}" == "1" ]
then
    echo "script ret: " $RET >> $LOG
fi
```

To see the output click the following link [Ideone](http://ideone.com/dceC4) I seem to be getting 1.1 instead of 1.1 when I should be getting 001

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not work:

```
oldFile= `printf "%020d" ${RET_VAL}`
```

Remove the space after `=`

Comment: what is wrong with the formatting? I am still a beginner with bash so please excuse me

Comment: @Djj You are asking for left padding 20 spaces with zeros. You should use `printf "%03d" ${RET_VAL}`, as that will use `3` characters, zero padding if necessary.

Comment: @SpencerRathbun oh right -_- I didn't know thats what the 20 represented. Thank you

Comment: @Djj If you're new to bash scripting, I suggest reading the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).